# Advantage of Encrypted XML message over HTTPS messages on C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, http-post, xml-encryption

I am designing an **`XML over https` message communication** in my application.

My PM thinks doing `x509.2 encryption to XML` and transport message over `https` will be better secured.

I was wondering, as message is being transferred over `HTTPS`, it is already encrypted.

**So will x509.2 encryption bring any additional security? or is it just an overhead?**

These messages are simple `HTTPWebRequest` and `HTTPWebResponse` types

Additional security

1. Client and Host are under `firewall`
2. `HTTPWebRequest` carries Authorization tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just overhead. It's already secured using SSL. It's *technically* more secure to encrypt the XML as well but unless you are extremely concerned about the security of this data it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: What kind of protection can I expect by encrypting the XML?

Comment: I think it depends on what sort of encryption protocol you are using. If you symmetrically encrypt the XML and send the key along with it, I would say you get no benefit. If you have a public key of where you are sending it, you could encrypt with that and it would be very secure.

Comment: This is with public key. So encryption over https is adding some security? But I don't get what additional protection will this public key gives that https is not giving?

Comment: The only real advantage is that if somehow the HTTPS connection was compromised, the XML would still be encrypted.

Comment: How can https connection be compromised? don't mind, trying to know all possibilities.